# "Bene docet, qui bene distinguit."

Tags: reference-request, passage-identification

Where does the phrase "***Bene docet, qui bene distinguit.***" ("He who teaches well distinguishes well.") come from?

James T. Bretzke in [*Consecrated Phrases*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=9365) says this is a

> Classical adage which refers to the fact that the truth of a certain position is found in attention to those important details which distinguish it, or set it off, from another position or issue. This adage emphasizes the critical importance of making the proper distinctions in any argument or search for the truth.

Comment: I read somewhere that it came from Saint Thomas Aquinas, so not exactly ancient, as the word is used around here. I heard it as *qui distinguit bene docet.*

Comment: According to [this book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Collection_of_Legal_Maxims_in_Law_and/qMkEAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22bene+docet%22&pg=PA243&printsec=frontcover)  this is from the "Institutes of Lord Coke. " (or maybe Justinian). According to google books the first occurrence I saw is London 1665 (https://www.google.com/books/edition/Flora_Seu_De_Florum_Cultura_Or_A_Complet/PMZDAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22bene+docet,+qui+bene+distinguit%22+google+books&pg=PP24&printsec=frontcover )

Comment: @Figulus Yes, I've heard it in various word orders, e.g., "_bene docet qui distinguit_" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest to this I've been able to find is St. Thomas Aquinas, [*Sententia Metaphysicae* lib. 3 l. 14](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Metaphysics3.htm#14) n. 3 [517]:

> Et quamvis hoc dicere intendant, non tamen bene *dearticulant*, idest non bene distinguunt.
>
> <sup>And although they wanted to say this, they did not “express themselves” clearly; i.e., they did not clearly distinguish things.</sup>

His seeming neologism *dearticulant* seems synonymous with *docent*.